# Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Observable<Response>' to expected argument type '([_]) -> _'

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, moya

I ran into the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Observable<Response>' 
to expected argument type '([_]) -> _'
```

when I tried to compile:

```
func request(_ token: MyAPI) -> Observable<Moya.Response> {
    switch (target.requiresCSRF, target.requiresOAuth) {
    case (false, false): return actualRequest 
    case (true, false): return CSRFTokenRequest().flatMap { _ in actualRequest }
    case (false, true): return OAuthTokenRequest().flatMap { _ in actualRequest }
    case (true, true): return Observable.zip([CSRFTokenRequest(), OAuthTokenRequest()]) { _ in actualRequest }
    } 
}
```

actualRequest is of type `Observable<Response>`
both CSRFTokenRequest and OAuthTokenRequest is of type `Observable<String?>`

I'm trying to run **CSRFTokenRequest** before **OAuthTokenRequest** and then the actual request.

The following resolves the issue... but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it...

```
return RequiresCSRFTokenRequest().flatMap{ _ in
            self.RequiresAuthenticationRequest().flatMap{ _ in actualRequest}
        }



fileprivate extension Networking{

    func RequiresAuthenticationRequest() -> Observable<String> {

        /// This has 3 cases

        // 0. token is not present, error out
        // 1. token is not expired, return token
        // 2. token is expired, needs refresh

        guard let jwt = AuthManager.shared.accessToken else{
            return .just("Error!! No access tokens")
        }

        // If access token is valid
        if AuthManager.shared.expiredAccessToken == false{

            return .just(jwt)

        }else{

            return request(.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: AuthManager.shared.refreshTokenWithBearer!))
                .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
                .mapObject(type: UserAuthenticationTokens.self)
                .do(onNext: {
                    $0.save()})
                .map{ (token) -> String in
                    // Get new access token that was just saved
                    return AuthManager.shared.accessToken!
            }
        }

    }


    func RequiresCSRFTokenRequest() -> Observable<String> {

        // Always get a new csrf token
        return request(.getCSRF())
            .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
            .mapObject(type: CSRFToken.self)
            .do(onNext: {
                $0.save()
            }).map{ (token) -> String in
                return AuthManager.shared.csrf_token!
            }
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what are the returned types of all those expressions?

Comment: They should be Observable<String?>

Comment: What's `actualRequest`?. I suppose it's returning an `Observable<Moya.Response> isn't? Please share more about your types, it's very difficult to help you without more information

Comment: What happen when do you return in your function only the `actualRequest` `Observable`?(Delete everything else just `return actualRequest`)

Comment: It builds fine without switch chase and just return actualRequest

Comment: @user805981 See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see in your code if you see closely your last case in the `switch` statement and the fact that both functions `CSRFTokenRequest()` and `OAuthTokenRequest()` are returning `Observables<String?>` you're creating a new `Observable` that waits for both to emit.

`zip` emits the two Observables for you, in your case you're omitting both using { _ return actualRequest } . **But** be careful when you're returning the function `actualRequest` it expects another thing, so the point here is convert an `Observable<A>` to an `Observable<B>`.

For this, you will need to use the `flatMap` function as you did before, and you're missing it in your last case.

So let's see and example:

```
Observable.zip(Observable.just(1), Observable.just("!")) { (a, b) in
   return (a,b)
}
.flatMap {  _ in return Observable.just(4.0) }
.subscribe(onNext: { value in
    print(value)
})
.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

In the above case, I omitted the two values of the `Observable<Int>` and `Observable<String>` to create a new `Observable<Double>`

In your case you should do something like this:

```
return Observable.zip(CSRFTokenRequest(), OAuthTokenRequest()).flatMap { _ in actualRequest }
```

I hope this help you

Comment: I updated my post with a way to resolve the problem.... but I'm not sure if this is the right way to flatmap it... what would you suggest?

Comment: @user805981 No, it's not recommended at all put nested call to Observables, you should use instead chaining like `flatMap` does, see my updated answer

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'Observable<String?>' (aka 'Observable<Optional<String>>') to expected argument type '([_]) throws -> _'` Using your method now gives me the following... is there some sort of casting that must be done for Observables?

Comment: Yes indeed you have to cast at some point, but it's weird because you're omitting the result it not should be necessary

Comment: What would you sugget I do? I took a look at the Observable.zip return type and it looks like it is `Observable<Observable<Response>>` which doesn't line up with the function return type...

Comment: Yes, I suggest to instead of omit the parameters put the parameters for the functions in the closure and the type of return to you can follow what are expecting, something like this `Observable.zip(Observable.just(1), Observable.just("!")) { (a: Int, b: String) -> (Int, String) in return (a,b) }`

Comment: Those request Observables don't have parameters... they are just funcs that return and Observabe<String?>

Comment: In your case will be `Observable.zip(CSRFTokenRequest(), OAuthTokenRequest ).flatMap { (token1: String?, token2: String?) -> Observable<Moya.Response> in return YourFunctionHere }`

Comment: I'm thinking it maybe is caused by how I'm returning my observables ? Do you mind taking a look? Thanks! I updated the question with my source code for my token requests...

Comment: Is it safe to assume that Observable.zip is synchronous though? I'm not sure if it is or not....

Comment: No not at all, `zip` is asynchronous in fact RxSwift is a framework for async tasks